# Max usable watts for DRV8825 board

Tags: stepper-motor, charger

I want to supply an energy from notebook adapter to `17HS8401 alloy stepper motor` with attached `DRV8825` board. My notebook adapter says:

```
output:
19.5V
2.31A
45W
```

I know that board can handle 8.2V〜45V2.5A, but I'm not sure about the `watts` How could I determine it?

Also do I need an electrolytic capacitor somewhere in adapter? If yes, is 35V, 100μF enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motor is rated for 1.8A and [Resistance: 1.8± 10% Ω/Phase](https://bc-robotics.com/shop/stepper-motor-nema17-73oz-in/)  thus  3.24V when stationary or 5.8W per  phase or 11.6W max per motor.  Perhaps you want a bigger 24V motor.  Can the board PWM down to 3.24V average or current limit to 1.8A?   Pref. a low ESR 220uF 35 V cap  to handle the high ripple current with PWM and stepping.

Comment: thanks for the explaining! I try to look for a bigger one